# Why should an ol element's overflow attribute be hidden, to expand it as much as possible in the x-axis direction

Tags: css, overflow, hidden

I made a simple navigation menu that detects hover over buttons and changes color. I refered to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float5).

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<ul class="menu_button_container">
  <li><a href="about:blank" class="menu_button">hi</a></li>
  <li><a href="about:blank" class="menu_button">bye</a></li>
  <li><a href="about:blank" class="menu_button">asfd</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
li {
    float: left;
  }
  
  .menu_button{
    padding: 10px 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .menu_button:hover {
    background-color: #111;
  }

  .menu_button, .menu_button_container{
    background-color: gray;
  }
  .menu_button_container{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;  <!--here the problem line-->
    padding: 0px;
    width:100%;
  }
```

If I delete the problem line, ol element doesn't expand in x-axis direction.

I try to delete the problem line, expecting the program will operate without change.

It is completely different from my expectation.
According to what I leared, overflow property determines how to react when the element 'overflows'
but the width of the ol element is too short to overflow.(its parent is body)

Answer (score 1):

`float: left;` takes your `<li>` out of the normal flow of the document. This means they don't contribute to the height of their parent element. The [overflow property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow), when set to a value other than visible, establishes a new block formatting context. This means the parent element contains the floated elements, causing it to expand to include them. If you remove `overflow: hidden;` the `menu_button_container` doesn't establish a new block formatting context, and won't expand to include the floated elements. To solve this you need to clear the floats:

```
.menu_button_container::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I am not sure that I understand exactly. Why `width:100%` that I wrote to make menu_button_container to expand doesn't work?

Comment: @beingaddictedtocoding When you float elements they do not affect the size of their parent element, and the parent element behaves as if the 'floated' element is not there when calculating height (or sometimes width). Normally, width:100% would make the element take up 100% of the available space, but floated elements aren't counted as a part of that parent element because they are removed from the document flow (they *can* overlap or be overlapped by other content). To solve this we "clear the float" to ensures that the parent container fully encompasses its floated children.

Comment: @beingaddictedtocoding [Clearing floats](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/explain-the-purpose-of-clearing-floats-in-css/) - Here is a site that explains "clearing floats" more in depth.